# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' but I made the string an Interger

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this really frustrating error that I can't seem to fix, it tells me that the "<" is not supported by strings and integers but I made sure I converted them into integers using the int() function

```
import random

print("Hi what is your name?")

name = input()

print("And your age please?")

age = input()

print(f"Now {name} pick a number that is lower than your age ({age}) but bigger than zero")

number_pick = input()

if number_pick != "":
    int(age)
    int(number_pick)
    if number_pick > 0:
        print(f"Good choice now the result of your {age} timesed by {number_pick} is..")
        print(age * number_pick)
    else:
        print("your number doesnt follow the requirements")
else:
    print("Please write your number pick")
```

I am lost for ideas, what should I change?

Comment: `age = int(input())` and `number_pick=int(input())`? You have to save back again the converted values in some variable

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int(number_pick)
```

This cast returns the result of the conversion, but you aren't storing it anywhere.

```
number_pick = int(number_pick)
```

You may also want to add some error checking:

```
try:
    number_pick = int(number_pick)
except TypeError:
   print("Please make sure you are entering in a number")
```